# Why are Android popup messages called toasts?

Tags: android, toast

My guess it that the lightweight notifications in Android are called [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) because they popup like toast from a toaster.  Can anyone confirm this or provide a better explanation?  I am teaching a course on Android development and would like to edit the wiki, so I want to be sure to get it right.

Comment: That would be a reasonable assumption, it was mine too :)

Comment: I thought it was the drink toast idea too, and even if that's not the origin it's a better explanation and should be the official metaphor of toasts.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Quoting [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Toast_%28computing%29) :

> An ex-Microsoft employee of Google is
>   credited with coining the term during
>   the development of MSN Messenger,
>   since Messenger's small notification
>   windows slide upward into view, **like
>   toast popping out of a toaster**

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I personally do not like the name, but now I at least understand where it comes from. When you consider that a toast message can be anything that "pops up", it makes more sense than when you just consider the acknowledgement aspect of it.

Comment: The link to wikipedia is out of date, since the quoted article was merged into antother. Here is a permanent link: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Toast_%28computing%29&oldid=459336160

Comment: [citation needed] … I wonder *where* he is credited.

Comment: a toast to being toasty

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Now I wonder, what about the Snackbar?

Answer (score 19):

And I always thought it was like a toast with a glass of wine, where you give a short message like "to your health" or "happy birthday" or "contact deleted".

But a toaster make more sense.

Comment: A friend of work remembered the "Toasty!" from Mortal Kombat videogame. We both thought the "Toast" came from that reference :) http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130113213400/mortalkombat/pt/images/6/6e/Zzzxxxtoasty.png

Comment: Pretty sure it was spelled "Tooaasttyyy!", but still a solid point.